# Least Square Estimators of Alternate Model

Tags: least-squares

We are given the following regression model:

$y_i = \beta_o+\beta_1(x_i-c)+\epsilon_i$

where c is a constant. We are asked to derive the least squares estimators. Then assuming c is the mean of the $x_i$'s, we are asked to show that the least squares estimators are normally distributed random variables and statistically independent.

I attempted to derive $\beta_o$ & $\beta_1$ using the squared error of the line and worked my way through till I got the partials at the minimum point and arrived at:-

**$$\beta_1 = \frac{\bar y-\beta_o}{\bar x-c}$$
$$\beta_o = \frac{\bar y - \overline y\overline x + c\bar y - \beta_1((\bar x - c)-(\bar x^2 + c^2 -2c\bar x))}{1-\bar x + c}$$**

In the second part, by substituting $\bar x$ for c I arrive at:

$$\beta_1 = \bar y - \beta_0$$
$$\beta_0 = \bar y$$
I am asking for help to confirm these results. Also I can see that $\beta_o$ is normal since it depends on $\bar y$ but I am not sure how I would show that. Furthermore, how do we show that $\beta_1$ is normal and finally how they are statistically independent (can we just say the $cov(\bar y, \beta_1)$ is always zero?)